# Create Virtual directory in IIS with Inno Setup

Tags: iis, cmd, inno-setup, virtual-directory, appcmd

Hi I need a help to create a Virtual directory.

I tried use these commands, but none works:

```
[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; parameters: "/C""net %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd add vdir /app.name: """"Default Web Site/"" /path:/SERVER1 /physicalPath:D:\server1 /username:USER /password:PWD"

Filename: "net.exe"; parameters: "%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd add vdir /app.name: """"Default Web Site/"" /path:/SERVER1 /physicalPath:D:\server1 /username:USER /password:PWD"

Filename: "{cmd}"; parameters: "/C""%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd add vdir /app.name: """"Default Web Site/"" /path:/SERVER1 /physicalPath:D:\server1 /username:USER /password:PWD"

Filename: "{cmd}"; parameters: "%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd add vdir /app.name: """"Default Web Site/"" /path:/SERVER1 /physicalPath:D:\server1 /username:USER /password:PWD"

Filename: "cmd.exe"; parameters: "/C "%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd add vdir /app.name: """"Default Web Site/"" /path:/DSERVER /physicalPath:D:\server1 /username:USER /password:PWD""

Filename: "cmd.exe"; parameters: "%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd add vdir /app.name: """"Default Web Site/"" /path:/SERVER1 /physicalPath:D:\server1 /username:USER /password:PWD"
```

Comment: Does any of these work when you execute them manually on command-line?

Comment: Yes, I used this command in DOS:

%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\APPCMD add vdir /app.name:"Default Web Site/" /path:/SERVER1 /physicalPath:D:\server1 /username:USER /password:PWD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct syntax:

```
[Run]
FileName: {sys}\inetsrv\appcmd.exe; \
    Parameters: "add vdir /app.name:""Default Web Site/"" /path:/server1/ /physicalPath:D:\server1 /username:USER /password:PWD"
```

---

Your attempts didn't work because:

- In many, you try to run `net`, why?
- You have the quotes all wrong.

  > To embed a double-quote character inside a quoted value, use two consecutive double-quote characters.

  See [Parameters in Sections](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=params).
- Environment variables (`%systemroot%`) are resolved on command-line or in a batch file, but not in general when providing arguments to programs. If you want Inno Setup to resolve the variable for you, use syntax `{%SystemRoot}`. Though in this case, it's better to use `{sys}`.

  See [Inno Setup Constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts).
- While not a problem on its own, there's no point trying to run `.exe` (`appcmd.exe`) via command-interpreter (`cmd.exe`).